# Flipped conv2 output when trying to apply a Sobel filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, computer-vision, convolution

I have the following image that I am convolving with a Sobel filter:

[image]

At row 157, the color begins to change and we see that the intensity increases. Note in my MATLAB code, I converted the image to grayscale. This behavior can be seen below:

[image]

I then apply the following Sobel Filter:

```
Gy = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; +1 +2 +1];
A = conv2(im, Gy);
```

I expect the output to be a matrix with positive numbers since the intensity increases. However, the output shows a matrix with negative numbers. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conv2` rotates the kernel / filter mask by 180 degrees before performing filtering.  This is the definition of convolution (a.k.a. you're using `conv2` - 2D convolution). The positive changes you're expecting as the result is from the process of performing **correlation** instead.  As such, either use [`filter2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html), or rotate the kernel by 180 degrees by doing `Gy = Gy(end:-1:1, end:-1:1);` and then call `conv2` after so that inside `conv2` it will rotate the kernel **again** so that you're performing correlation instead.

As such:

```
Gy = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; +1 +2 +1];
Gy = Gy(end:-1:1, end:-1:1); %// Added
A = conv2(im, Gy);
```

Similarly, if you have access to the image processing toolbox, you may use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) as already suggested by another answer and the default behaviour is to use correlation instead of convolution.  You can override this behaviour by specifying the `'conv'` flag if you expressly want to perform convolution instead.